# Wifi, BT on RPi4

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-4

Question is very straightforward:

Who is the manufacturer of the onboard Wifi of RPi4?

All datasheet and specs only shows:

> 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz IEEE 802.11ac wireless, Bluetooth 5.0, BLE

I'm interested of the current manufacturer and module/chip type number.

Also, I'd like to know if BT and Wifi are provided by the same module/chip on RPi4?

Comment: Why is the downvote? At least have the courage to describe your reasons...

Comment: Ah, so you want to know if the SAME guy is making both the BLE and WiFi stuff squeezed into Pi4? I am curious to know why you want to know that?

Comment: Because I want to learn

Comment: For example on Pi3 it was by Cypress: CYW43455.

Comment: "Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information."

Comment: I know what a downvote means. Here I just did not understand the reason, and without communicating anything that can be also a failure of the reviewer who is not really involved in the topic. If we want to help StackExchange sites to continue growing and become even more popular, we must help each other instead just judging and downvoting.

Comment: I agree with you Daniel. I am trying to find exactly as you were and it's not easy. 99% of my searches always end up with how to configure Bluetooth in someway on the PI. That is not what I want. I want to know the MCU so I can work with the MCU directly...perhaps using a DK at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wireless support is provided in an RF shielded module by the same Cypress CYW43455 chip as we saw on the Raspberry Pi 3, Model B+. Offering dual-band 2.4GHz and 5GHz IEEE 802.11.b/g/n/ac wireless networking, as well as Bluetooth 5.0 and Bluetooth LE.

source: [goolge "manufacturer of wifi chip on raspberry pi 4" - first link](https://www.hackster.io/news/meet-the-new-raspberry-pi-4-model-b-9b4698c284)

Comment: Then you search on google for CYW43455 and it gets you to the official Cypress page which states this chip only supports BT4.1: https://www.cypress.com/documentation/datasheets/cyw43455-single-chip-5g-wifi-ieee-80211nac-macbaseband-radio-integrated

Comment: So how is BT5.0 integrated? :)

Comment: https://launchstudio.bluetooth.com/ListingDetails/72609 - more info: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1523836&sid=f01f21a858b6af35e24fff6d53cc3780#p1523836 ... `Emill expressed things very well. About the only changes to Bluetooth on the Pi4 is the response to the version number being 5.0 vs. 4.2.` - basically it's BT5.0 - but without all *optional* BT5.0 features

Comment: That was exactly the info I was hunting for. Thanks.

Comment: OMG, so you are betting on Cy, and like me, more interested in company listing than computer program listing? PS - 5G has already come to my town, and I am placing a long bet/plan.

Comment: @tlfong01 - I understood none of that

Comment: @Jaromanda, my apologies. My question is for Daniel:)